# Dead code in lesscss javascript compiler

Tags: javascript, less, dead-code

it looks like there is a bunch of dead code (code that is commented out) in the lesscss javascript compiler code.  Is there a reason for this?  When downloading right from the [website](http://lesscss.org/) the file is 34kb, after removing the dead code it is 5.78kb (left in the copyright comments).

Comment: Can you give more details on the _dead code_ ?

Comment: a bunch of code is commented out.

Comment: I just checked the minified version which has 34kb. There are no comments except for the short header. I'm afraid I can't help you. - http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.1.3.min.js

Comment: @Smamatti you need to scroll all the way to the right

Comment: After reading _Rob W_'s answer: Please check you syntax highlighting in your editor. `"//"` is a string (quotes!) not a comment start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I throw the LESS JavaScript code at a [compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/), rarely any code disappears.

When I view the code in my editor (Kate), the Syntax highlighting marks a large part of the code as comments, starting from:

```
(i.charAt(0)=="/"?i=a.location.protocol+"//"+a.location.host+i:i=g.slice(0,g.last
                                         ^^ From here on
```

This error is probably caused by the size of the string (34KB at *one* line). When I add a linebreak before `+"//"....`, the syntax highlighting works as intended.

Comment: `"//"` is a usual string. Is not the comment 'operator' `//` - Kate is interpreting this wrong. Syntax highlighting works fine in Notepad++ here.

Comment: @Smamatti `"//"` is correctly hightlighted when I split the line. When the code is at one line (34 kB !), however, the syntax highlighter gets confused.

Comment: you're absolutely right.  My editor (Sublime text 2) is doing the same thing.

Comment: @Smamatti As I said, it's a **highlighting issue** at the editor, caused by **a large string at a single line**. I did not develop Kate, but I understand that arbitrary large data can cause odd errors at complex string manipulation applications.

Comment: @Rob W Sorry. Got mixed up there. Removed that comment.